# I have a request params and a response data about a BI chart. I want to know what framework/technics used in the backend

Tags: backend, bigdata, business-intelligence

I have a request params and a response data about a BI chart. I want to know what framework/technics used in the backend. Or you can recommend me use which framework/technics to implement a BI system.

Here is the request params:

```json
{
  "selections": [
    {
      "type": "Standard",
      "key": "current_status",
      "asColumn": "x[0]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Agg",
      "key": "variant_id",
      "asColumn": "y[0]",
      "aggregation": "count",
      "parameters": [],
      "considerDistinct": false
    },
    {
      "type": "Agg",
      "key": "activity_name",
      "asColumn": "y[1]",
      "aggregation": "count",
      "parameters": [],
      "considerDistinct": false
    }
  ],
  "sortCriteria": [
    {
      "asColumn": "y[1]",
      "sortKind": "DESC",
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "asColumn": "x[0]",
      "sortKind": "DESC",
      "order": 2
    }
  ],
  "includeNullValues": true,
  "size": 4000,
  "filterList": {
    "type": "FilterList",
    "mode": "AND",
    "filters": []
  }
}
```

Here is the response data:

```json
{
  "headers": [
    "x[0]",
    "y[0]",
    "y[1]"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "Pay Invoice",
      10611,
      84521
    ],
    [
      "Review Purchase Requisition",
      2239,
      9820
    ],
    [
      "Reject Purchase Requisition",
      741,
      2223
    ],
    [
      "Return Material",
      239,
      1367
    ],
    [
      "Process Invoice",
      99,
      396
    ]
  ],
  "status": "Success",
  "isScrollingFurtherImpossible": false
}
```

And here is the chart rendered by the response data:
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what is the question. You mentioned API request to some BI backend, this can be either some popular BI product or maybe in-house BI system API. Most BI products have a backend that has a similar API.

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko I would like to know if there are any tools or frameworks for BI.

Comment: Examples of BI backends ('headless BI'): Cube.js (open source), PivotData microservice (commercial / includes rendering of tabular reports)